# Do rounds progress independently from scenes?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

A crossfire card is drawn at the start of each round. When a scene is ended in the Crossfire mission, do rounds reset so the next player to go draws the crossfire, or are rounds independent from the boundaries of where scene endings fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounds are independent from where scenarios begin and end. In fact, when I play we are cognizant of that and will try to make sure a scenario finishes right before the next Crossfire card is drawn